# Laravel 5.8 apply global scope on newQuery like 4.2 did

Tags: php, laravel

I am upgrading a laravel 4.2 project to 5.8.

In 4.2, I used the global scope trait to automatically add where conditions to my models. The where conditions would be added on 'newQuery' and were the first where conditions.

Now in 5.8, I added my global scope using the new way, it does not add the where conditions from the scope on 'newQuery', it applies the global scope conditions on 'get' by appending the where conditions to the query. This does not match my DB indexing, I can't do this, I need my global scopes to be applied on 'newQuery'.

```
class TenantScope implements Scope
{
  public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
  {
    $builder->where($model->getQualifiedTenantColumn(), '=', \idweb\helpers\SessionHelper::getTenantId());
    $builder->whereNull($model->getQualifiedDateDeletedColumn());
  }
}

// when I do this:
$q = \myapp\MyModel::query();

// the following test should be true with my two where conditions applied from the scope
// with laravel 5.8, this fails, the scope has not been applied yet
$this->assertEquals(2, count($q->newQuery()->wheres));

$q->where('cat', 'dog');
$list = $q->get();

// this uses db query, which is wrong
select * from mymodel where cat=dog and tenant=1 and date_deleted is null;

// the query needs to be by having the scope applied on newQuery, not get:
select * from mymodel where tenant=1 and date_deleted is null and cat=dog;
```

How do I get my scope applied on 'newQuery' like 4.2 did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not documented, but you can use 'extend' instead of 'apply'. 'extend' fires when the query is initiated so the where clauses are first.

In my scope class:

```
  /**
   * @param Builder $builder
   * @return void
   */
  public function extend(Builder $builder)
```

Answer (score -1):

To assign a global scope to a model, you should override a given model's `booted` method and use the `addGlobalScope` method:

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::addGlobalScope(new TenantScope);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing. When you do this, the scope is applied on 'get'. I need it applied on 'newQuery' so the 'where' clauses are the first conditions, not the last conditions.